# How can I read formatted text from a .doc or .htm file with xcode?

Tags: xcode, jformattedtextfield

I think this is a noobish question but I've been experimenting all morning and can't get this to work. Thanks in advance to any help.

I'm trying to make an app that displays formatted text based on the user's selection. I have a detail view that has a UIlabel on it. I have made it so it can pull text from a .txt file but I'd really like to pull that text formatted. Either in a .doc file or a .htm file (or anything I can keep formatting in really).

The files are loaded into xcode in the resource folder. The following works but it displays a bunch of ascii text in the UIlabel:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Testing1" ofType:@"htm"];
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
detailViewController.detailItem = textFromFile;
```

Do I have the encoding wrong? Should I not be using a UILabel? I've tried using a UIWebViewer but not sure this is right either.

I apologize in advance if this doesn't make much sense. I'm pretty new to all this and trying to learn as I go. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Meh, I got it to work finally with a UIWebView object. I'm not sure this is the best way, but it works finally! Figured I'd post it here in case anyone else is looking for a way to do this:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Testing1" ofType:@"htm"];
NSString *htmlBody = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:baseURL];
```